# DTrace `pid` provider does not trigger some `return` probes

Tags: macos, debugging, rust, profiling, dtrace

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. I have a library written in Rust and I need to measure the running time spent inside the library. I set up some `pid` probes like this (not the actual script):

```
pid$target::*parse*:entry
{
}

pid$target::*parse*:return
{
}

pid$target::*re_match*:entry
{
}

pid$target::*re_match*:return
{
}
```

The corresponding test code looks like:

```
let xxx = xxx_of_len(10);
let m = re_match(RE_XXX, &xxx).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", m);
```

The implementation of the `re_match` function in my library is:

```
pub fn re_match(re: &str, s: &str) -> Result<MatchResult, Error> {
    let prog = Compiler::compile(&Parser::parse(re)?)?;
    let mut vm = Vm::new(&prog);
    if vm.run(&s.chars().collect()) {
        return Ok(MatchResult::Match(vm.groups.clone()));
    }
    Ok(MatchResult::NotMatch)
}
```

The issue is, the two `return` probes cannot be triggered while the `entry` probes work normally. Also, if I set up the `entry` and `return` probes for the `Compile::compile` function in the same way, both probes work.

So what may be the cause of this issue and how should I work around it?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Brendan Gregg's blog post](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/02/14/dtrace-pid-provider-return/), the issue may be caused by compiler optimizations, where DTrace is confused by the optimized code so that it's unable to create certain `return` probes. To turn off the optimization, we can add the following content to the `Cargo.toml` of the test program:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 0
```

After doing this I can find the desired `return` probes with command:

```
sudo dtrace -l -n 'pid$target:::return' -c './path/to/test/binary'
```